# How to draw an n-Sided Area with Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to draw a n-Sided Area with Three.JS. All Vector3's and their order are given and added to the geometry vertices array. The coorinates all look like (x,0,y)

**How I can fill the area with faces?** Is there a function or is it an mathematical problem to split the area in triangle?

How I can solve this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the Shape object to achieve your objective.

```
myshape = new THREE.Shape();
```

or

```
myshape = new THREE.ShapeGeometry();
```

Demo here: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html

or you simply draw a path and fill it afterwards

```
context.lineWidth = 0.05;
context.beginPath();

// draw something

context.closePath();
context.stroke();
context.fill();
```

Hope that helps

ALA

Comment: Hello @ALA,

in a 2D Context this is the right solution. But I am in a 3D context, so it unfortunately doesn't work in my case. Any other ideas?